# Unable to load assets "assets/images/me.png" flutter using dart framework

Tags: flutter-image

[1. create directory : "assets"
2. create directory images inside "assets" and then put in image into it "me.png"

3. modify pubspec.ymal :
   flutter:
   uses-material-design: true
   assets:

   - images/me.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tB1wP.png)

`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          body: Center(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/me.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you rebuilt the application after adding these? I am not sure hot reload can handle new assets added.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.